# Running Nginx behind Traefik, problem with ports different than 80

Tags: docker, nginx, traefik

I want to run Nginx as static file server behind Traefik reverse proxy using Docker (docker-compose).

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: 
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  nginx:
    build: ./docker/dev/nginx/.
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.nginx.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.nginx.rule=PathPrefix(`/static`) || PathPrefix(`/media`) || Path(`/robots.txt`) || Path(`/favicon.ico`)
      - traefik.http.services.nginx.loadbalancer.server.port=80
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    listen [::]:80;

    ...
}
```

And it works,
But when I try to change internal nginx port to another, lets say 8082, Traefik returns 502 error and prints `'502 Bad Gateway' caused by: dial tcp 172.21.0.6:8082: connect: connection refused"` in debug logs.

By changing port I mean:

- replacing `traefik.http.services.nginx.loadbalancer.server.port=80` with `traefik.http.services.nginx.loadbalancer.server.port=8082` in docker-compose.yml
- replacing `listen 80; listen [::]:80;` with `listen 8082; listen [::]:8082;` in nginx.conf

I have other apps in config, like Django running on gunicorn server. There is no problem for gunicorn to listen on 3000 port, and for Traefik to forward incoming :80 requests to :3000.
Why doesn't it work with nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have told nginx to listen to 8082 port which is ok, but the container has to expose the port. (I guess by default the container expose 80 port)

You seem to have a custom nginx image, so you can add/replace the [EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) keyword in your image to have something like this : `EXPOSE 8082`.

You have to build and restart the container for the change to take effect, then you can check the exposed ports with `docker-compose ps`.

Comment: You are right, I have forgotten about `EXPOSE`, I wonder why I dont have to expose port in my python/django container and it still works. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: It's surely because the base Image you are using expose a port, which become kind of a default port for your image.